# Start celery workers with multiple brokers

Tags: python, redis, celery

Currently, i have a `celery.py` with a single redis broker

```
proj/celery.py

from __future__ import absolute_import

from kombu import Exchange, Queue
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('proj',
             broker='redis://myredis.com'
             backend='redis://myredis.com'
             include=['proj.tasks])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

i would start a worker with:

```
celery multi start somename -A proj -Q work -c20 --pidfile='somepidfile' --logfile='somelogfile'
```

over multiple machines (let's say 20..)

so these workers across 20 machines use a single broker,

```
'redis://myredis.com'
```

I would like to split that so that 10 machines use `'redis://myredis.com'` and other 10 machines use `'redis://myredis2.com'`

What changes do I need to make that happen?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that will be to have a DNS that resolves to both `redis://myredis.com` and `redis://myredis2.com` in a round-robin fashion. Provided that you have enough workers, this should roughly split the 2 brokers evenly.